# Custom headers in Websocket Protocol messages

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm using Netty to create a WebSocket application. I'm able to send HTTP Headers during start of connection but I'm unable to send custom headers with messages after establishing connection.

Is it possible to send custom headers with messages after establishing connection in WebSockets? Any example would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to encode it in your web socket payload.